# Cannot run dbt deps command on macos. Having an permission error

Tags: macos, dbt

I'm trying to run `dbt deps` command but i get this error `OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/mnt'`

I tried disabling system integrity protection but i still have the same error.
Is there a way to run dbt deps and bypass that /mnt folder or install it somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the variable : `packages-install-path`
By setting another folder, it solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

You could download the dbt packages you want to use and add them as [local packages](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/packages#local-packages) in your `packages.yml`:

```yaml
packages:
  - local: relative/path/to/subdirectory
```

Instead of using a relative path you could try if your platform supports other kinds of pattern:

```yaml
packages:
  # not recommended - support for these patterns vary
  - local: /../../redshift   # relative path to a parent directory
  - local: /opt/dbt/redshift # absolute path on the system
```

Answer (score 0):

`dbt deps` will create folder `dbt_packages` under the dbt root directory. Which means it requires write permission to the dbt root directory.

There are two alternatives could to solve this issue.

- Copy (or clone) the folder to a writable partition.
- Make the folder writable, if you directly open a mount file, this might not be possible. Just use the first alternative, after mount it copy to another folder.